# Can I attack even after striking a deal?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

I struck a deal with a slaver vessel. I will spare them for a slave. How do I attack after a successful deal? They are bad after all.

Comment: In addition to the given answers, it's worth noting that if you really like calling backsies on your acceptance of surrender, you could download The Captain's Mod, which will allow you to accept surrender from most enemies, then carry on shooting them anyway. This assumes, of course, that you don't care about suffering a mutiny.

Comment: @ymbirtt you can suffer a mutiny in the mod or is that a new feature?

Comment: @JFA, that's part of the mod. As far as I know there is nothing that can be described as a mutiny in either the base FTL or Advanced Edition.

Comment: I believe you also have the option of suffocating the crew of the slaver ship, which if done successfully rewards you with the much-higher scrap reward of a suffocated crew AND a slave sometimes

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you end an encounter with a peaceful resolution, there's no way to manually force an attack.  The only option is to move on.

The [Friendly Slaver](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Friendly_Slaver) event has a special "blue" option if you have a level 2 teleporter where you can get a crew member *and* initiate combat.

However, as I mentioned, there's no way to choose a different outcome once you've completed the event.

Comment: I do think if you're using missile weapons and one is in-flight when you broker your deal, that one missile may still end up hitting (and potentially killing) the slavers. Similarly, if their ship is on fire when you make your deal, it's possible for the fire to kill the slavers and destroy their ship even after the deal is concluded. That's all just down to luck, though.

Comment: @AdamV, yeah, attacks in flight can sometimes destroy a ship after peace has been made.  I think I've also wiped out the last crewmember after peace was attained.  I'm not sure you get a reward from that, though, right?  It's only happened to me once or twice.  At any rate, in the scenario the asker describes, I think they never started combat, so there's no way to start it now.

Comment: @agent86 I've destroyed ships via fire and such after a truce was negotiated many times.  You get no reward for doing so other than the satisfaction of seeing them *asplode*.

Comment: @BlackVegetable, thanks for confirming my shaky memory :)

Comment: AFAIR, weapons *do* miss after surrender and all combat stops, but I'm 100% sure the fire/breaches/solars/asteroids still damage/kill afterwards.

Answer (score 7):

No, if you choose to purchase from them you will not be able to attack the slaver vessel during the [Friendly Slaver Vessel](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Friendly_Slaver%E2%80%8E) event.

If you want to obtain potentially 2 crew members from this event, you will need at least a rank 2 teleporter and pick the blue option in an attempt to free some slaves.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in many cases the ship can still be destroyed after a surrender. This happens if you have some shots in the air, or if their ship is on fire (and you wait), for example.

So yes, you can destroy the ship after striking a deal, however you can't *attack* them after striking the deal.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @DJPirtu fixed; forgot to mention the last sentence